# When and how do the Manifestation powers of Ephemerals come into play?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

The section on Ephemerals in the *Demon:The Descent* manual and *Chronicles of Darkness* manual describes Manifestation powers for Ephemerals and even gives a map of how they interact. However I don't see any example of opponents that actually use the mechanics of Fettering and Reaching and Anchoring etc. Even the book on Night Horrors doesn't seem to have any opponents that use them. It's as if you read the rules for chess and the book described in great detail how magic affects how the pieces interact but no chess game you've seen or heard about uses them.

It might be that these powers are central to other splats such as Geist and Werewolf. If so, can you point to a particular manual that gives a good example of their use?

Answer (score 1):

After poking around a bit I found that the splats dealing explicitly with "ghosts" (Wraith: the Oblivion and Geist: the Sin-eaters) routinely refer to fetters, anchors, etc. The problem is that the Ephemerals section in some of the CoD books deals generically with angels, ghosts, and spirits while specific splats have each as major actors in their storylines (Demon: the Descent, Geist: the Sin-eaters and Werewolf: the Forsaken, respectively). The general rules in the Ephemerals section don't have the details that are specific to DtD, GtS, or WtF.

By providing the general Ephemerals section the core books give a set of possible 
antagonists that can be used in multiple settings without invoking all of the baggage of every storyline. This compromise means that the context for the rules is not as well explained as in the relevant storyline manual.